# Div content misalignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is my jsfiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/ducyaLan/)

```
The text content written within the <div>'s moves up
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?
What's the fix for this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change the div's `line-height` to 1

Comment: @OriDrori Yes even this works! Add it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get rid off the `line-height: 8%;` property from `.rule` class.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `float:left` to the rule class.

Your alignment fixed code. Only thing i added is float

```
.rule{
    height: 8%;
    line-height: 1%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answered fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/ducyaLan/1/

```
.rule{
    height: 8%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.event {
    height: 8%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```